# if statement breaking my generated email

Tags: php, email, if-statement

I have the following email generated automatically.  When it is triggered and I am sent an email, I only get "MESSAGE PART 1".  The if statement, and everything after the if statement (including REST OF MESSAGE) never gets sent.  How can this be done?

```
/*----SEND EMAIL TO STUDENT----*/
$to      = $studentEmail;
$subject = 'Title';
$message = 'Dear '.$studentFirstName.',

MESSAGE PART 1';

if ($bubbleWrap == true) {
'Bubble Wrap ($5)';
}

'REST OF MESSAGE';

$headers = 'From: CustomerService@GuysAndDollies.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: customerservice@GuysAndDollies.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the remaining strings with the original:

```
$message = 'Dear '.$studentFirstName.', MESSAGE PART 1';
if ($bubbleWrap == true) {
    $message .= 'Bubble Wrap ($5)';
}
$message .= 'REST OF MESSAGE';
```

Currently you just have two [string literals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) which will do absolutely nothing on their own.

Comment: ah!  thank you, I knew I was missing something tiny, but I just couldn't figure it out.  I will mark this answer correct in 9 mins when I am allowed to. Thanks for your help and going over something so basic with me!